# Perform a group by query on geodatabase in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, sql, layers, file-geodatabase

I have a geodatabase called predictions.gdb and a feature class called output_gis_120_Project in that database. I imported this feature class as a layer in ArcMap. The attribute table with columns lat,lng,attrx,attry,avg_price which is in the form

>

- lat1,lng1,attr1,attr2,avg_price1
- lat1,lng1,atrr3,attr4,avg_price2

etc... I would like to perform a sql query which is

> SELECT lat,lng,SUM(avg_price) from output_gis_120_Project GROUP BY
>   lat,lng;

I read that ArcGIS can only have group by statements in a subquery so I went to layer--->properties-->definition-->query builder and rewrote my query as

> "select * from output_gis_120_Project where lat,lng,sum_price in
>   (SELECT lat,lng,SUM(avg_price) sum_price from output_gis_120_Project
>   GROUP BY lat,lng)

I keep on getting an error saying that there was an error with the expression. I tried putting the fields in brackets [] and only selecting avg_price in the subquery, but this didn't help either.

Comment: what type of geodatabase do you use ? note that .gdb do not support all queries.

Comment: I'm not sure what ArcGIS's limitations are in regards to GROUP BY, but you cannot have a WHERE ... IN specified like that. Must have one column only. See syntax here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp

Comment: Why do you have this tagged with `mysql`?  File geodatabse doesn't have a RDBMS, so even valid ANSI SQL isn't fully supported.

Comment: how would I find out what type of .gdb I'm using? It just says file geodatabase. Also I tried only one column in where like where avg_price in (SELECT SUM(avg_price) from output_gis_120_Project GROUP BY lat,lng). Is there a different way to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Comment: The .gdb indicates it's a file geodatabase, rather than a personal geodatabase (.mdb) -- personal GDBs have more thorough SQL support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To complete these type of relational database queries using an ArcGIS geodatabase (not a relational database as mentioned above) you will have to use a tool like [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000)

To do the groupings, use the 'case' field (ie. the field you want to group by)

The SUM option `Adds the total value for the specified field.`

Comment: @TimnitGebru fantastic!