# Area of contours, broken lines

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, line, contour

I have flown topo lines covering a large AOI. Some of these lines stretch across the whole area and therefore aren't closed while others just cut off and also aren't closed. I want to calculate the area of the lowest 5 contour lines per each basin (polygon).

I tried extending the lines and then converting them into polygons but this didn't work because some of them did not close.

How do I find the lowest 5 lines per each basin (there are about 35)?

I am using ArcMap 10.3 and AutoCAD Civil 3D. My company does not have the spatial analyst package.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Which software are you using?

Comment: Thank you! I am using ArcMap 10.3 and AutoCAD Civil 3D however, my company does not have the spatial analyst package.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  Please **edit** the question in response for requests for clarification.  It's also policy to have one question per Question.  Please take the 2-minute [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) which explains how things work here.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer 1 of your questions.  If you only have 35 lines per basin, query by basin type, sort your table, and select the 5 lowest elevations.  Done.
For 35 records per basin, is it worth the effort to automate?

If you had more records to deal with, I would suggest creating summary statistics and using them to create a nested SQL query to select the 5 lowest elevations in each basin.  If you're interested, there is documentation on that here:

Summary Stats:  http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000001z000000

Grouping with summary stats:  [Perform a group by query on geodatabase in ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114369/perform-a-group-by-query-on-geodatabase-in-arcmap)

Subqueries:  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm#GUID-D1BFDC51-62DD-4090-B5AC-826FCF766F6A

If you need to assign the basins to the lines, use the intersect tool and set Join Attributes to ALL.

Comment: After researching the queries a bit more, the best solution to automate this would be a search cursor.  Let me know if you're interested and I'll provide a code sample.